# end result of bash command with a dot (.)

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, grep

I have a bash script that greps and sorts information from /etc/passwd here

```
export FT_LINE1=13
export FT_LINE2=23
cat /etc/passwd | grep -v "#"  | awk 'NR%2==1' | cut -f1 -d":" | rev | sort -r | awk -v l1="$FT_LINE1" -v l2="$FT_LINE2" 'NR>=l1 && NR<=l2' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/, */, /g'
```

The result is this list

```
sstq_, sorebrek_brk_, soibten_, sirtsa_, sergtsop_, sec_, scodved_, rlaxcm_, rgmecived_, revreswodniw_, revressta_,
```

How can i replace the last comma with a dot (.)?  I want it to look like this

```
sstq_, sorebrek_brk_, soibten_, sirtsa_, sergtsop_, sec_, scodved_, rlaxcm_, rgmecived_, revreswodniw_, revressta_.
```

Comment: Why `rev` the lines right before sorting them? `... | cut -f1 -d":" | sort -r` would give you the same result. Then, `grep` works on a file, so you don't need to `cat |` — instead `grep -v "#" /etc/passwd | awk...` — that's _two_ processes eliminated from the pipeline.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need all the users reverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are way to many pipes in your command, some of them can be removed.

As explained in the comment `cat <FILE> | grep` is a **bad habit**!!! In general, `cat <FILE> | cmd` should be replaced by `cmd <FILE>` or `cmd < FILE` depending on what type of arguments your command does accept.

On a few GB size file to process, you will already feel the difference.

This being said, you can do the whole processing without using a single pipe by using `awk` for example:

```
awk  -v l1="$FT_LINE1" -v l2="$FT_LINE2" 'function reverse(s){p=""; for(i=length(s); i>0; i--){p=p substr(s,i,1);}return p;}BEGIN{cmp=0; FS=":"; ORS=","}!/#/{cmp++;if(cmp%2==1) a[cmp]=reverse($1);}END{asort(a);for(i=length(a);i>0;i--){if((length(a)-i+1)>=l1 && (length(a)-i)<=l2){if(i==1){ORS=".";}print a[i];}}}' /etc/passwd
```

**Explanations:**

```
# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
        cmp = 0   #to be use to count the lines since NR can not be used directly
        FS = ":"  #file separator :
        ORS = "," #output record separator ,
}

# Rule(s)

! /#/ { #for lines that does not contain this char  
        cmp++ 
        if (cmp % 2 == 1) { 
                a[cmp] = reverse($1) #add to an array the reverse of the first field
        }
}

# END rule(s)

END {
        asort(a) #sort the array and process it in reverse order

        for (i = length(a); i > 0; i--) {
                # apply your range conditions
                if (length(a) - i + 1 >= l1 && length(a) - i <= l2) { 
                        if (i == 1) { #when we reach the last character to print, instead of the comma use a dot
                                ORS = "." 
                        }
                        print a[i] #print the array element
                }
        }
}


# Functions, listed alphabetically
#if the reverse operation is necessary then you can use the following function that will reverse your strings.
function reverse(s)
{
        p = ""
        for (i = length(s); i > 0; i--) {
                p = p substr(s, i, 1)
        }
        return p
}
```

If you don't need to `reverse` part you can just remove it from the `awk` script.

**In the end, not a single pipe is used!!!**

Comment: Definately going to use this next time! but for now, is there anything I can add on to what I wrote above that would replace the comma at the very end of the list with a period?

Comment: @GabeSpound: then you can use the solution of ruakh `sed 's/,$/./'` it should work fine ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can add:

```
| sed 's/,$/./'
```

(where `$` means "end of line").

Comment: I don't think this would work, I only want to replace the last comma